# How to create a NAS/NFS distributed over multiple machines?

Tags: mount, nfs, nas, cluster

I have multiple mac minis running Ubuntu. I'm building a mini cluster. Each has a medium sized drive. I was wondering if there was a way I could turn a portion of each drive into a shared NAS/NFS of sorts. I realize it wouldn't be the fastest solution, but I'm looking for a way to utilize all the storage.

Basically what I am looking for is a way to take 100 GB from 5 different machines and have it appear as a 500 GB shared volume. Is this even possible, or is it just a really bad idea?

Comment: I don't know anything about it, but it seems like you need a distributed storage cluster, such as ceph.